# Actionscript - the syntax is incorrect

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I tried to compile this, but there is an error in the code.
In this section:

```
}
private function arrNametoString(_arg1:Array):String{
var _local2 = "";
_arg1.reverse();
var _local3:int;
while (//unresolved if
, true) {
_local2 = (_local2 + String.fromCharCode(_arg1[_local3]));
_local3++;
};
return (_local2);
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you decompile this code? If so, why exactly don't you write your own in this case? (it looks like a trivial function)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is in your `while` loop

It should be:

```
while (true) {
    _local2 = (_local2 + String.fromCharCode(_arg1[_local3]));
    _local3++;
};
```

But it looks like there's a comment in there regarding the while loop statement.

```
//unresolved if
```

Which is stating that the while loop is going to be stuck in an infinite loop.

Also be careful with untyped variables: `var _local2 = "";` should be `var _local2:String = "";`